# How to modify the HTML tag in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6

I am new to Drupal and I need to add an attribute to the HTML tag, but I cannot find the way. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably depends in part on your theming mechanism.  However, the doctype and html tags are likely hard-coded in `page.tpl.php` or similar (located in sites/all/themes/themename).  The exact file will depend on your theme.

For example, I have a site with the following in `page.tpl.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>">
```

As you can see, there is some information being injected by PHP.  This would be the place for you to make your change.

Comment: I have the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589627/how-to-modify-the-html-tag-in-joomla-1-5) for Joomla.  Any idea where I might find something similar?