# How to modify the HTML tag in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I need to define an appcache manifest on the login page.  I found [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353852/how-to-modify-the-html-tag-in-drupal-6) asked about Drupal 6, but the file mentioned, `page.tpl.php`, does not exist.  Where is the counterpart in Joomla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML tag should be in the template index.php found here -

JOOMLA INSTALL/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/index.php